# jquery - use on with load to execute a function dynamically

Tags: jquery, load, onload

I wish to execute a function every time that a div tag with specific class is added in html page.

For example :

I add dynamically :

```
<div class="myform" id="myID"></div>
```

and function go_form() is executed.

I try a code :

```
$(document).on("load", ".myform", function(){
   var div_id = $(this).attr("id")
   go_form(div_id)
});
```

but it don't work.

Thanks for your help !!!

Comment: You might want to lookup `MutationObservers`

Comment: where do you dynamically add the div....why don't you call the function afterwards?

Comment: How do you add a dynamic div in html, using AJAX? If yes the just call the function in AJAX success function.

Comment: Yes I add my div using ajax.

Comment: ajax produce html content. The div tag have parameters to load automatically other contents. In fact I want to separate html engine to javascript and execute javascript after creation of html code.

Answer (score 0):

There are various complex ways to do this -- [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) being the obvious one. However, as your own code is inserting the element, I'd simply fire an event when the code is inserted and listen for it using another function.

So, in your function that adds the new element, use this. You'll need to set the variable `newForm` to contain the form you've just created.

```
$(document).trigger("formadded", [newForm]); // you can use whatever event name you like
```

And where you want to respond to the form's new existence:

```
$(document).on("formadded", function(form) {
    go_form(form);
});
```

Or, to simplify it even further:

```
$(document).on("formadded", go_form);
```

See [the documentation for `trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not exactly what I want. 
In this case I must create a trigger before launch my function. My problem is that I don't know if my ajax add my specific div in my html document. My idea is simple : dissociate totally engine html to javascript. Javascript must execute specific function depending to class of my div. Like that I produce with ajax a template with many div tags and javascript load in those div tag specific data...

Comment: @E.Dimauro I don't really understand your point. Are you saying that your AJAX function adds a chunk of HTML where you don't know what's in it? Then test it and find out. If you have JS making changes to the DOM, they are *not* totally dissociated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the another way to DOM changes -

```
$("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
    if($(this).find('#myID')){
       // Call your function here
    }
});
```

OR if you have mainDiv under body just use this -

```
$("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', "#mainDiv", function() {
        if($(this).find('#myID')){
           // Call your function here
        }
});
```

Comment: In my case I must replace #mainDiv by .myclass and unfortunatily It don't work...

Comment: Thanks ! 
you things that DOMSubtreeModified can detect added div tags ?

Comment: I hope thik so.

Comment: Just try with my first code and test with any console log to test.